# Doing Norbert's Gambit with free-transaction ETFs? (QTrade)

Tags: etf, foreign-currency

Can we perform cheap currency conversion like Norbert's Gambit by trading something else than DLR and DLR.U to avoid/reduce the ETF purchase and sale fees?

For big trades, the gambit has potentially huge savings, but for small-ish sums like 1K-2K, the $9.95 CAD + $9.95 USD ETF transaction fees to buy, then sell (or vice versa) can make the whole process cost-prohibitive (at least on QTrade).

Is there any way to take advantage of a [commission-free ETF](https://www.qtrade.ca/investor/accounts/etfs) available in two currencies to save some fees? The ETF wouldn't be necessarily be tied to currency values, like DLR(.U) is, but I'm thinking maybe there's room to play if we're not too worried about volatility of a particular stock.

Comment: Is the Gambit even worthwhile any more now that cheap currency transfer services exist?

Comment: @GS do tell! maybe I'm out of touch with the latest scoop. are you talking about transferwise, remitbee, or the like? With Norbert's gambit the overall exchange fees (outside the commission) are extremely slim, even counting the bid/ask spread.

Comment: right, I was thinking about Transferwise/Revolut etc. I think with both you'd be spending about 0.5%-0.8% off the notional mid-market exchange rate, though the fee structures vary.